# Passing previously assigned variable in `{% for` block in Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

In `blog-templte.liquid`

```
{% assign articleSortOrder = '' %} 
 ....

{% for article in blog.articles {{articleSortOrder}} %}
```

got an error : `Liquid syntax error: Unexpected character { in "article in blog.articles {{articleSortOrder}}"`

The intention is to pass the variable to sort the articles depending on some condition.

Q: is how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid liquid code:

`{% for article in blog.articles {{articleSortOrder}} %}`

You can't pass a liquid inside a liquid, a.k.a `{% {{ }} %}`

---

In addition for loops accept only a few parameters:

- `reversed` - which will reverse the loop
- `limit` - which will limit the iterations
- `offset` - which will make the loop skip a specific set number of items

Sort is not one of them.

You can read more about the for loop here: https://shopify.dev/docs/liquid/reference/tags/iteration-tags

---

In order to sort the blog in a specific way you must code it like so:

```
{% assign articleSortOrder = '' %} 
{% assign blog_articles_sort = blog.articles | sort: articleSortOrder %}
{% for article in blog_articles_sort %}

{% endfor %}
```

Where you assign the articles in a specific variable and sort them.

Please have in mind that this will sort ONLY 50 articles.

---

If you like to sort more than 50 you will need to overwrite the paginate object `{% paginate blog.articles by 9999 %}`

Then your code will look like this:

```
{% paginate blog.articles by 9999 %}
  {% assign articleSortOrder = '' %} 
  {% assign blog_articles_sort = blog.articles | sort: articleSortOrder %}
  {% for article in blog_articles_sort %}

  {% endfor %}
{% endpaginate %}
```

More about paginate can be seen here: https://shopify.dev/docs/liquid/reference/tags/theme-tags/#paginate

---

Please have in mind that the sort function in Shopify is limited. You may need to sort them with javascript or another approach depending one what you are looking for.